# What aggregation cursor methods are supported by Nodejs drivers?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

As you know from 2.6 on Mongodb `aggregate()` operation returns a cursor, however [the behavior is a bit different](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#cursor-behavior)  than the normal cursor which returns from a `find()`. I am using native mongodb nodejs driver, and could not find a proper documentation on available aggregate cursor methods.

For example, one cannot run a `count()` on an aggregation cursor however there are two methods such `cursor.objsLeftInBatch()` and `cursor.itcount()` n mongo shell. I could not find any of them in the source code of nodejs native driver. What aggregation cursor methods are supported by Nodejs native driver or Mongoose?

Comment: The question i had been searching for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What actually gets returned from aggregate with a cursor is a [node transform stream interface](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) with a few other convenience methods, notably:

```js
explain: [Function],
get: [Function],
getOne: [Function],
each: [Function],
next: [Function],
```

Which you can obtain by simply dumping the cursor object using `console.log`. Those should be self explanatory with the `get()` method being equivalent to `.toArray()`.

Since this is a standard streaming interface the methods and event handlers are available as per this interface, so with an example:

```js
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/test", function(err,db) {

    var items = [];
    var counter = 0;

    var cursor = db.collection('tags').aggregate(
      [
        { "$project": {
          "t1": 1,
          "t2": 1
        }}
      ],
      { "cursor": { "batchSize": 25 } }
    );

    console.log( cursor );

    cursor.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log( this );  // dump the current state info
      items.push( data );
      counter++;
    });

    cursor.on('end', function() {
      console.log( "Iterated " + counter + " times" );
    });

  });
```

The "data" event is fired with each cursor iteration and properties on the object will show whether the stream is complete or still iterating and so on.